# Export notes on website to Google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get all the notes on my website to get exported onto Google drive. I have a pop up window with a "Save to drive" button but I can't figure out what file this HTML needs to be converted to. Also not sure how to convert the HTML into the certain file that Google drive needs.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#getting_started), the button is configured with a few attributes in a `div` tag in the HTML markup. You need to include the necessary JavaScript resource below to add the Save to Drive button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Basic Page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-savetodrive"
         data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
         data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
         data-sitename="My Company Name">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#examples).